# Как избавиться от повторного написани кода

Tags: javascript

Подскажите каким способом можно избавиться от дублирования вызова методов.
Пытался использовать `example.[flag]('dima1')` но это не валидно. Править  класс Example нельзя

```
class Example{
  and(text) {
    console.log(text, '-and')
  }
  or(text) {
    console.log(text, '-or')
  }
}

const example = new Example()

const flag = 'and'

if (flag === 'and') {
  example.and('dima1')
  example.and('dima2')
  example.and('dima3')
} else {
  example.or('dima1')
  example.or('dima2')
  example.or('dima3')
}
```

Comment: Избавляться от того, что применяешь ключевые слова метода - довольно глупо... явно не то место, где надо избавляться от "дубля". В таком случае паттерн builder  обладает просто тотальной хромотой потому что можно писать огромные цепочки методов повторяясь

Comment: Это будет валидно, если не будете писать точку перед квадратными скобками

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант.

```js
class Example{
    printWithPostfix(text, postfix) {
        console.log(`${text}-${postfix}`)
    }
}

const example = new Example()

let flag = 'and'

example.printWithPostfix('dima1', flag)
example.printWithPostfix('dima2', flag)
example.printWithPostfix('dima3', flag)

flag = 'or'
example.printWithPostfix('dima1', flag)
example.printWithPostfix('dima2', flag)
example.printWithPostfix('dima3', flag)
```

Если менять класс Example нельзя, то избавиться от дублирования можно следующим образом.

```
example['and']('dima1')
example['and']('dima2')
example['and']('dima3')
example['or']('dima1')
example['or']('dima2')
example['or']('dima3')
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение, указал на ограничение правки класса Example

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Example {
  and(text) {
    console.log(text, '-and')
  }
  or(text) {
    console.log(text, '-or')
  }
}

const example = new Example();

const flag = 'and';

['dima1', 'dima2', 'dima3'].forEach(example[flag]);
```